# Python exec() NameError: name 'o' is not defined

Tags: python

This code chunk here was intended to look for any occurrences of a letter in one list, and if it finds any, it replaces the value in the second list with the same index value.

```py
iWord = ['_', '_', '_', '_']
cWord = ['w', 'o', 'o', 'd']
letter = 'o'

def updateList(x, y):
    global iWord
    global cWord
    global letter
    bomb = f"iWord[{x}] = {y}"
    exec(bomb)
    print(iWord)

[updateList(x, y) for x, y in enumerate(cWord) if y == letter]
```

Expected result:

```
['_', 'o', 'o', '_']
```

Actual result:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\night\Desktop\RGL\Code\test.py", line 13, in <module>
    [updateList(x, y) for x, y in enumerate(cWord) if y == letter]
  File "c:\Users\night\Desktop\RGL\Code\test.py", line 13, in <listcomp>
    [updateList(x, y) for x, y in enumerate(cWord) if y == letter]
  File "c:\Users\night\Desktop\RGL\Code\test.py", line 10, in updateList
    exec(bomb)
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'o' is not defined
PS C:\Users\night\Desktop\RGL>
```

Comment: `bomb` is this: `iWord[1] = o` You need quotes around o, otherwise it is treated as a variable name.

Comment: Or, better, make it `{y!r}` to add whatever quoting is correct for the specific value.

Comment: But why on earth would you use `exec` and such a convoluted way for such a simple task?

Answer (score 0):

When you use string formatting, it doesn't include the quotes on strings. Rewrite your formatters to use the REPR-form of strings:

```
iWord = ['_', '_', '_', '_']
cWord = ['w', 'o', 'o', 'd']
letter = 'o'

def updateList(x, y):
    global iWord
    global cWord
    global letter
    bomb = f"iWord[{x!r}] = {y!r}"
    exec(bomb)
    print(iWord)

[updateList(x, y) for x, y in enumerate(cWord) if y == letter]
```

Alternatively, call `repr()` directly:

```
iWord = ['_', '_', '_', '_']
cWord = ['w', 'o', 'o', 'd']
letter = 'o'

def updateList(x, y):
    global iWord
    global cWord
    global letter
    bomb = f"iWord[{repr(x)}] = {repr(y)}"
    exec(bomb)
    print(iWord)

[updateList(x, y) for x, y in enumerate(cWord) if y == letter]
```

Answer (score 0):

This code is wrong on so many aspects. I don't know if the purpose was to use `exec` for fun but this is really not needed. Also using a list comprehension as a loop to execute a function without output is not a recommended practice.

Here are pythonic ways to achieve your goal.

Defining a new list:

```
iWord = [b if b==letter else a for a,b in zip(iWord, cWord)]
```

Modifying the list in place:

```
for i,x in enumerate(cWord):
    if x == letter:
        iWord[i] = letter
```

Output: `['_', 'o', 'o', '_']`